# Java, Query a series of .HTML Help

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out what is nessary to preform what I belive to be a somewhat simple task, but it seems its execution is a bit advance.

Can someone provide an example that might help me figure out the following goal?

1. Check various known .html files on local server for a string
2. If string is Que_for_board the preform a parse of other strings that will be in file
               Example: Release data, Author, Program etc
3. Else (if Que_for_board not found)  go to next HTML
4. Takes results in and print to a file

Is this is hard as it seems? I've looked into HTMLCleaner parser but not sure I need to clean up the HTML into XML, and Im finding it hard to find a query code that has the next step in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I would not describe this as a truly hard task, in that it's really a matter of using a number of techniques that are "out there", but I can see that it could be intimidating.

A technique I find useful is to decompose the overall task into small problems, and teach myself to think only about one problem at a time, having faith that I can assemble the overall solution eventually.

So here you have perhaps

1. get a list of files from somewhere (where? directory listing, a document?)
2. Open each file in a list in turn
3. parse an html file
4. find a specific string in the parsed file

Of these parsing html files is potentially very easy or not so easy. Can you trust the file to be well-formed or was it written by a human? Humans simply don't make good HTML files and browsers are very tolerant of missing `</P>` etc.

If these are very simple html files you can fake this by using simple String searching, regex and so on. Otherwise you need a proper parser, and maybe a clean up first.

My first step would be to understand how to process a single HTML file.